# SQL Query: order by length of characters?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Is it possible to order sql data rows by the total number of characters?

e.g. `SELECT * FROM database ORDER BY data.length()`

Comment: Did you try running that SQL statement?

Comment: For those looking to do this with SQLAlchemy, combine [`desc()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=desc#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.desc) with [`func()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=desc#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func), as alluded to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15743220/594137).

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I think you want to use this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length

(MySQL/MariaDB specific)

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(field)
```

You can use just simply LENGTH(), but beware, because it counts the byte number (which won't give you the expected result with multibyte strings).

Comment: See Alex Reitborts answer below if you're looking for MS SQL Server variant.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Oracle.Just modify with:
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY LENGTH(field)

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Android Room query, it can only support: LENGTH(field)

Answer (score 76):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Len(data)
```

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY length(data) desc
```

Where data is varchar field

Answer (score 8):

For anyone doing with **Sqlite**

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY LENGTH(field) DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable ORDER BY LENGTH(Column_Name) DESC
```

e.g;

```
SELECT * FROM Customer ORDER BY LENGTH(CustomerName) DESC
```