# How to filter in `sqlalchemy` by string length?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How to filter in `sqlalchemy` by string length?

This code snippet:

```
sess.query(db.ArticlesTable).filter(or_(
    and_(db.ArticlesTable.shorttext.length > 0),
         ...
```

gave me the following error:

```
File "./aggregate_news.py", line 69, in is_acceptable
    db.ArticlesTable.shorttext.length > 0),
  File ".../sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 211, in __getattr__
    key)
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' 
    object associated with ArticlesTable.shorttext has an attribute 'length'
```

Where `ArticlesTable` is:

```
class ArticlesTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = TABLE_ARTICLES
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    shorttext = Column(String)
    ...
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to use the [`func` SQL function generator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=desc#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) to create a `LENGTH()` function:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func

sess.query(db.ArticlesTable).filter(or_(
    and_(func.length(db.ArticlesTable.shorttext) > 0),
```