# Query in one-to-many relationship

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables which their relation is one-to-many

```
class User (db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_model'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  db.Column(db.String(50), nullable = False)
    messages = db.relationship ('Message' , cascade = 'all,delete', backref = 'user_model' , lazy = True)
```

```
class Message (db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'message_model'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    context =  db.Column(db.Text, nullable = False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user_model.id'))
```

Assume for a specific user (user with id = 1) I want to retrieve all messages which are related to this user and the message length is less than 50.
How can I do this?
Something like this:

```
user = User.query.get (1)
messages_less_than_50 = user.messages.query.filter (len (Message.context) < 50)
```

Am I able to query on user.messages ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter in \`sqlalchemy\` by string length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743121/how-to-filter-in-sqlalchemy-by-string-length)

Comment: No. my question is how can I query on a list which is in one side in one-to-many relation. @noslenkwah