# Filter by string length less than in Flask SQLalchemy?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

In Flask SQLAlchemy, I am trying to return all records where the string length in the title column is less than 60 characters.

I tried:

`Users.query.filter_by(len(self.obj.title) < 60).all()`
returned type error: *TypeError: object of type 'InstrumentedAttribute' has no len()*

I then tried:

`Users.query.filter_by(len(self.obj.title.str) < 60).all()`

It didn't return an error, but no queries were returned, even though there ARE records in the db with title column string lengths less than 60 characters.

Finally, inspired by the following [q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743121/how-to-filter-in-sqlalchemy-by-string-length) i tried:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func

Users.query.filter_by(func.length(self.obj.title.shorttext) < 60).all()
```

Again though, no error, but nothing returned.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is a typo but it is not possible to use the length function in `filter_by` since it only take keywords arguments not expressions.

Anyway when using the query *filter* method it requires classes (e.g. `Users`) not objects. Therefore the filter would be written as follows in Flask SQLAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func

Users.query.filter_by(func.length(Users.title) < 60).all()
```

References:

- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter
- https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/#querying-records