# how do i fetch sqlite column based on its len and limting 10 using python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Trying to list sqlite3 value from highest to lowest limited it to 10 using python,
here's my current code

```
connection   = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
database     = connection.cursor()
all_user     = str(database.execute("SELECT logtext from logs order by logtext limit 10 ")
```

I can't figure the logic of using ***len(logtext)***
and how to actually list from highest to lowest limiting them by 10.

Comment: Is logtext a text field? `order` will order alphabetically - I'm not clear what you mean by "highest to lowest". `limit 10` will return (at most) the first 10 rows. What does `len(logtext)` have to do with this? Why are you treating the (non-existent) return value of `execute` as a str? Instead of using `fetch...` methods.

Comment: logtext column has characters in it..
I want to fetchall based on which column has more characters
and by highest to lowest i mean * order by logtext DESC * only logtext highest characters

Comment: You want to sort by the **length** of the `logtext` field? That wasn't at all clear - can you edit the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT logtext from logs order by length(logtext) desc limit 10")
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/3606923/960709